# Getting an Uniform Type Identifier for a given extension

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, uti

I'm trying to find some way in Cocoa to translate from file extensions to Uniform Type Identifiers. That is, I want to find some way of doing this:

```
".jpg" => "public.jpeg"
".html" => "public.html" 
".ttf"=> "public.truetype-font"
```

I've searched on the NSWorkspace docs but couldn't find anything. The closest I could get was:

```
- (NSImage *)iconForFileType:(NSString *)fileType
```

that returns the icon for a file extension, and

```
– (NSString *)preferredFilenameExtensionForType:(NSString *)typeName
```

that does exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. Do any of you know how to do this?

I really hope I don't have to check for a lot of extensions by hand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I needed this about a week ago:

```
NSString * UTI = (NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, 
                                                                   (CFStringRef)[myFilePath pathExtension], 
                                                                   NULL);
```

If I run this on the extensions @"php", @"jpg", @"html", and @"ttf", it prints:

```
public.php-script
public.jpeg
public.html
public.truetype-ttf-font
```

---

**Update 11+ years later**:

In Swift, there are two ways to do this, depending on your deployment target:

1. If you want to run on macOS Catalina and *earlier* (before Big Sur) or iOS 13 and earlier:

   ```
   let fileExtension = "html"
   let unmanagedString = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension as CFString,
                                                               fileExtension as CFString, 
                                                               nil)

   let typeIdentifier = unmanagedString?.takeRetainedValue() as String?
   ```

   The `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag()` func (still part of the `CoreServices` module) returns an `Unmanaged<CFString>?`; this is a type that *boxes* a `CFString` and you need to indicate (via one of the `.take...` methods) what the memory management semantics should be.

   Since the function follows [the Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) naming pattern, it's going to return a `CFString` to us that we need to take ownership of. Therefore we use `.takeRetainedValue()` to *transfer* the ownership of the `CFString` from the manual memory management world into the ARC world.

   Then there's a decent amount of bridging to go from `String` to `CFString` and vice versa.
2. macOS Big Sur (and iOS 14) got a new `UniformTypeIdentifiers` module that makes this a whole lot simpler:

   ```
   let fileExtension = "html"
   let typeIdentifier = UTType(filenameExtension: fileExtension)
   ```

Comment: Just don't forget that because the function name has `Create` in it, you're responsible for `release`ing the object.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. 

I had some problems initially, but it was because I was not trimming whitespace and newline characters from the path strings. (I am reading them from a command line tool.)

Comment: I needed this just today. :-) It's even cleaner if you wrap it like so: `NSString *uti = [NSMakeCollectable(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)[myFilePath pathExtension], NULL)) autorelease];`

Comment: You should know, that in order to get this code snippet to work on iOS, you must `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

Comment: what is the Swift 5 equivalent for this?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the Terminal and invoke **mdls** which gives you all kinds of information on a certain file type including UTIs.

```
mdls /myPath/to/myFile.ext
```

mdls will then show you the associated UTIs in kMDItemContentTypeTree
(it's also possible to call mdls from within your Cocoa App btw).